# Silverlight XAMLParserException while trying to apply Styles

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I was in the process of Migrating my application from Silverlight 3 to Silverlight 5.

I understood from the developer forums that Silverlight 5 XAML parser is very strict. I was encountering the error **'Name/key cannot be found'** when refernenced by Other Assemblies.  Actually i have this piece of code (below code) in a Theme (Theme.Xaml) in **Utilities** Class Library and I am trying to set the Style of that to the Default ScrollViewer.

Visual Studio highlights this line as warning (with squiggligly line) during compile time.

`Style="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer}">`

```
<ScrollViewer BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                          Style="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer}">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Can someone help me resolve this situation ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have that style in app.resources?

Comment: sometimes the code compiles even though xaml errors are shown in the error window. It happens when you have the xaml file open. Is this the case?

Comment: @Sajeetharan The Sytle is not defined in App.Resoures as it is not a style. I am trying to get the Styles from System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer

Comment: Your templates still exist in SL but you're not going to reference them via a namespace or anything like that. If you want the default instead just try `Style="{StaticResouce DefaultScrollViewerStyle}" to get the template. However unless you've got the default overridden somewhere then just stripping the Style declaration all together should make it use the default automatically.